# How to properly accessing/distribute an application that uses a MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm fairly new to C# and completely new to databases.

Currently I've created a database of movies and a GUI to go along with it. I can query the database fine but I have a question about accessing and distributing my application.

Right now I have to run mongod.exe before starting my application. My understanding of this is that mongod.exe lets my program access the database.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way for my application to run without needing to explicitly run mongod.exe?
2. If so, how?

The reason I ask is because I want to distribute my application among several computers and I don't want to install MongoDB on every computer and have to have mongod.exe running before each start of my application.

If I'm completely misunderstanding the issue would someone mind pointing me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mongod must be installed somewhere whether it is a hosted service by someone like MongoHQ or on a remote server or even the clients computer. MongoDB cannot exist without...MongoDB.

If you wish to distribute your app why not make a central DB server for them to talk to? This would be a better way of doing it.